# Add multiple dataframes based on one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, average

I have several hundred dataframes with same column names, like this:

## df1

```
        wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave  
0    4050.32    3  0.28269  0.07365  22.16080  4050.311360   
1    4208.98    5  0.48122  0.08765  44.90035  4208.972962   
2    4374.94    9  0.71483  0.11429  86.96497  4374.927110   
3    4379.74    9  0.31404  0.09107  30.44271  4379.760601   
4    4398.01   14  0.50415  0.09845  52.83236  4398.007473 
5    5520.50    1  0.06148  0.12556   8.21685  5520.484742
```

## df2

```
        wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave  
0    4050.32    3  0.28616  0.07521  22.91064  4050.327388   
1    4208.98    6  0.48781  0.08573  44.51609  4208.990029   
2    4374.94    9  0.71548  0.11437  87.10152  4374.944513   
3    4379.74   10  0.31338  0.09098  30.34791  4379.778009   
4    4398.01   15  0.49950  0.08612  45.78707  4398.020367   
5    4502.21    9  0.56362  0.10114  60.67868  4502.223123   
6    4508.28    3  0.69554  0.11600  85.88428  4508.291777   
7    4512.99    2  0.20486  0.08891  19.38745  4512.999332
8    5520.50    1  0.06148  0.12556   8.21685  5520.484742
```

That's how i0'm reading them

```
path_to_files = '/home/Desktop/computed_2d/'
lst = []

for filen in dir1:
   df = pd.read_table(path_to_files+filen, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')

   lst.append(df)
```

The desired result should look like this:

```
      wave   num   stlines      fwhm        EWs  MeasredWave
0  4050.32   3.0  0.284425  0.074430  22.535720  4050.319374
1  4208.98   5.5  0.484515  0.086690  44.708220  4208.981496
2  4374.94   9.0  0.715155  0.114330  87.033245  4374.935812
3  4379.74   9.5  0.313710  0.091025  30.395310  4379.769305
4  4398.01  14.5  0.501825  0.092285  49.309715  4398.013920
5  4502.21    9   0.56362   0.10114   60.67868   4502.223123   
6  4508.28    3   0.69554   0.11600   85.88428   4508.291777   
7  4512.99    2   0.20486   0.08891   19.38745   4512.999332
8  5520.50   1.0  0.061480  0.125560  8.216850   5520.484742
```

As you can see the number of rows are not same. Now i want to take the average of all the dataframes based on column1 `wave` and i want to make sure that the each index of column `wave` of `df1` gets added to the correct index of `df2`

Comment: do you want average for each row based on column values ?

Comment: yeah, i want to take average of the rows that are common in both dataframe based on column1 'wave'

Comment: What if some index are not present in some data frames?

Comment: i want to keep them as well.! @Arihant

Comment: Is it to be performed for all the columns or only `wave` column?

Comment: I want to do this operation on all columns except 'wave'

Comment: @GyanenderGandhar Can you post your desired output for those sample `df1` and `df2` you provided?

Comment: yeah i've just added the desired result. @SaiKumar

Comment: @GyanenderGandhar wanted to use value in column `wave` as index to find corresponding rows in all the dataframes. Then compute average values for all the relevant column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack all dataframe in one by using pd.concat wich axis = 1 and take average of respective column

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['wave'],how ='outer',)
df4 = df3.rename(columns = lambda x: x.split('_')[0]).T
df4.groupby(df4.index).mean().T
```

Out:

```
    EWs         MeasredWave fwhm        num stlines      wave
0   22.535720   4050.319374 0.074430    3.0 0.284425    4050.32
1   44.708220   4208.981496 0.086690    5.5 0.484515    4208.98
2   87.033245   4374.935812 0.114330    9.0 0.715155    4374.94
3   30.395310   4379.769305 0.091025    9.5 0.313710    4379.74
4   49.309715   4398.013920 0.092285    14.5 0.501825   4398.01
5   8.216850    5520.484742 0.125560    1.0 0.061480    5520.50
6   60.678680   4502.223123 0.101140    9.0 0.563620    4502.21
7   85.884280   4508.291777 0.116000    3.0 0.695540    4508.28
8   19.387450   4512.999332 0.088910    2.0 0.204860    4512.9
```

Comment: i don't want to take the average of each column. what i want to do is like, if first index of column 'wave' of df1  is there in df2 then take the average of rows, otherwise just keep that row as it is.

Comment: @GyanenderGandhar i just edited code for your requirement.is it what you need

Comment: I created `df4` and `df5` just to illustrate `ignore_index`.  Actually I re-read the question but still do not understand. It is good if @GyanenderGandhar can provide sample df and desired output.

Comment: Hi, i've added the desired result. Have a look over it. @yoonghm

Comment: Hi @GyanenderGandhar i have tried same logic on that data, it is giving expected results for all values except "df['num'].loc[5]",

Comment: yeah i can see that, but still it's not correct. In the oringal data i,ve around 500 rows. so you can imagine the level of error.

Comment: actuallly 5th row is in same dataframes of df1 and df2 , so according to your logic it should give mean (9+1)/2 = 5 , can you plz check your conditions again @GyanenderGandhar

Comment: No, rows 5 isn't the same in both cases, there's another row on that index in df2.

Comment: @GyanenderGandhar i just added condition based on column 'wave' , plz check is that desired output ?

Comment: the order of columns got  changed but Yeah it worked.! Thanks for the help. @NagaKiran

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180158/discussion-between-gyanender-gandhar-and-naga-kiran).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to do what you need:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                    'B': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                    'C': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                    'D': [0, 1, 2, 3]},
                    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4, 5, 6, 7],
                    'B': [4, 5, 6, 7],
                    'C': [4, 5, 6, 7],
                    'D': [4, 5, 6, 7]},
                    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [8, 9, 10, 11],
                    'B': [8, 9, 10, 11],
                    'C': [8, 9, 10, 11],
                    'D': [8, 9, 10, 11]},
                    index=[0, 1, 2, 3])

df4 =  pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
df5 = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)
print(df4)
print('\n\n')
print(df5)

print(f"Average of column A = {df4['A'].mean()}")
```

You will have

```
    A   B   C   D
0   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3   3
0   4   4   4   4
1   5   5   5   5
2   6   6   6   6
3   7   7   7   7
0   8   8   8   8
1   9   9   9   9
2  10  10  10  10
3  11  11  11  11



     A   B   C   D
0    0   0   0   0
1    1   1   1   1
2    2   2   2   2
3    3   3   3   3
4    4   4   4   4
5    5   5   5   5
6    6   6   6   6
7    7   7   7   7
8    8   8   8   8
9    9   9   9   9
10  10  10  10  10
11  11  11  11  11

Average of column A = 5.5
```

Comment: No, that's not what i want to do.!

Answer (score 1):

Answer from @Naga Kiran is great. I updated the whole solution here:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
  {'wave'        : [4050.32, 4208.98, 4374.94, 4379.74, 4398.01, 5520.50],
   'num'         : [3, 5, 9, 9, 14, 1],
   'stlines'     : [0.28269, 0.48122, 0.71483, 0.31404, 0.50415, 0.06148],
   'fwhm'        : [0.07365, 0.08765, 0.11429, 0.09107, 0.09845, 0.12556],
   'EWs'         : [22.16080, 44.90035, 86.96497, 30.44271, 52.83236, 8.21685],
   'MeasredWave' : [4050.311360, 4208.972962, 4374.927110, 4379.760601, 4398.007473, 5520.484742]},
   index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
  {'wave'        : [4050.32, 4208.98, 4374.94, 4379.74, 4398.01, 4502.21, 4508.28, 4512.99, 5520.50],
   'num'         : [3, 6, 9, 10, 15, 9, 3, 2, 1],
   'stlines'     : [0.28616, 0.48781, 0.71548, 0.31338, 0.49950, 0.56362, 0.69554, 0.20486, 0.06148],
   'fwhm'        : [0.07521, 0.08573, 0.11437, 0.09098, 0.08612, 0.10114, 0.11600, 0.08891, 0.12556],
   'EWs'         : [22.91064, 44.51609, 87.10152, 30.34791, 45.78707, 60.67868, 85.88428, 19.38745, 8.21685],
   'MeasredWave' : [4050.327388, 4208.990029, 4374.944513, 4379.778009, 4398.020367, 4502.223123, 4508.291777, 4512.999332, 5520.484742]},
   index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='wave', how='outer')
df4 = df3.rename(columns = lambda x: x.split('_')[0]).T
df5 = df4.groupby(df4.index).mean().T
df6 = df5[['wave', 'num', 'stlines', 'fwhm', 'EWs', 'MeasredWave']]
df7 = df6.sort_values('wave', ascending = True).reset_index(drop=True)
df7
```